# Migrated from standard to flex App Engine environment, now Cloud SQL won't connect

Tags: postgresql, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

I have a Google App Engine app written in Node.js which connects to a Cloud SQL Postgres instance under the same GCP project. Previously I was using the standard environment and it worked fine, but when I switch to a flex environment, the SQL connection no longer works.

My `app.yaml`:

```
runtime: nodejs

env: flex

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1

beta_settings:
  cloud_sql_instances: mopho-217900:us-central1:mopho
```

I'm connecting to the DB through Knex with hostname `/cloudsql/mopho-217900:us-central1:mopho`. This gives me the following error:

```
Error: connect ENOENT /cloudsql/mopho-217900:us-central1:mopho/.s.PGSQL.5432
```

The username/password/database I'm providing are all valid, and continue to work if I switch back to the standard environment. It only fails when I switch to the flexible environment.

Comment: I don't have personal experience with this but you might check out the nodejs sample app.yaml at Github - https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docs-samples/blob/master/appengine/cloudsql/app.flexible.yaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the [Cloud SQL Admin API](https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/sqladmin.googleapis.com/) needed to be enabled. (thanks to [this Google groups post](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-appengine/IZgep9t3LbI/LKs8FB1UAQAJ) for the pointer)